# UIAlertViewController showing a bit of delay before actually presenting

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I have a UIAlertViewController that is taking a while to present and by a while its like a second or so.. The code is below.

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernameTextField.text!, password:passwordTextField.text!) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) in
        if user != nil{

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toMainView", sender: self)

    } else {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Entered User Creditinials Are Incorrect. Please Try Again.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

        })

        alert.addAction(action)

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Thank You In Advance :)

Comment: Might be called from a different thread, so use `DispatchQueue.main.async { }`. Also when used on a cell, I have noticed a delay and sometimes not showing up. Using `DispatchQueue.main.async` seems to work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code little bit and now UIAlertController popping up instantly. I used Parse.com Error Codes;

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernameTextField.text!, password:passwordTextField.text!) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if user != nil {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toMainView", sender: self)
        } else {
            let ErrorCode = error!.code
            switch ErrorCode {
            case 101:
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Entered User Creditinials Are Incorrect. Please Try Again.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (action: UIAlertAction!) in })
                alert.addAction(action)
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                break
            default:
                println(ErrorCode)
                break
            }

        }
    }
```

You can see Parse Error Codes [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#errors).

Comment: Your code is true, there is no problem and like i said UIAlertController popping up instantly for me. Is your other processes instantly? Maybe you have a internet connection problem? Parse doing this sometimes.